# Endless ListView + SwipeRefreshLayout best practice

Tags: android, listview, swiperefreshlayout

I've been trying to make a refreshing and auto updaing list in my app. I use Loaders to get data for that list. I saw a guide for endless `ListView` [here](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView) and it really makes your code neat. However, when i add `SwipeRefreshLayout`, `ProgressBar`and a view indicating empty list the code becomes a total mess and is not reusable at all. I was wandering if there is a nice way to implement this often used feature.

If you want to see my code, please ask in comments (But there's nothing significant in it..)

Comment: That was mine approach doing things some time ago : https://github.com/YuriiYurii/MoviewViewer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/yuriitsap/example/com/movieviewer/utils/MovieAdapter.java

Comment: @YuriiTsap Thanks for the link, but i'm not interested that much in an adapter for my list view. I want to understand if there's any way to write a controller for both `SwipeRefreshLayout` and `onScroll` method of `OnScrollListener` which handles endless scrolling.